# Find P with $PAP^{-1}=D$ with no calculations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have this exersize and we were told these 2 matrices can be diagonalized with no calculations at all.

We need to find P such that $PAP^{-1}=D$ is diagonal (if the matrices are diagonalizable) for both $A_1$ and $A_2$:

$A1=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
1 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 2 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$A2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 5 && 2 && 1 \\
1 && 2 && 0 && -1 \\
0 && 0 && 3 && 2 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 4
\end{bmatrix}
$

Characteristic polynomial is easy to find for both $A_1$ and $A_2.$

So $\chi_{A_1}(X)=(X-2)^3(X-1)^2$, but how can I see that it isn't diagonalizable without calculating $V_2$?

As for $A_2,$ $\chi_{A_2}(X)=(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)(X-4)$ which is diagonalizable. Now again how do I proceed from here without calculations?

- I know how to find eigenvectors and then build P according to the eigenvectors. I'm just asking if there is a quick way to solve the problem for these two?

Thanks!

Comment: $A_1$ is in Jordan form, with Jordan blocks of sizes $3,1,1$, so it is not diagonalizable. $A_2$ has 4 different real eigenvalues, so it is diagonalizable (the corresponding eigenvectors form a basis and $A_2$ in that basis is $diag(1,2,3,4)$).

Comment: If $A_1$ is diagonalizable, then $(A_1-2I)(A_1-I)=0.$ That is, the minimal polynomial for $A_1$ must have no repeated roots.

Comment: I don’t see what you mean by proceeding without calculation. Clearly, for $A_2,$ the value of $P$ depends on the specific values of $A_2.$ If you want to find $P,$ rather than just prove $P$ exists, you definitely need to do calculations.

Comment: It’s easier to find left-eigenvectors for $A_2,$ or eigenvectors for $A_2^T.$ Then $(0,0,0,1)A_2=(0,0,0,4).$ Also $(0,0,1,a)A_2=(0,0,3,4a+2),$ so the left eigenvector for eigenvalue $3$ is $(0,0,1,-2).$ The eigenvectors for eigenvalues $1,2$ are more work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If the question is to find the entries of $P$ such that $PAP^{-1} = D$, then we should really be looking at left eigenvectors shouldn't we? Assemble the left eigenvectors into the rows of $P$. If one looked at right eigenvectors we would get $P^{-1}$ and have to perform a 4x4 matrix inversion to get $P$.